# New line with `O` slight delay after `ESC` with `:set noesckeys`

Tags: vim

I still have the delay even after :set noesckeys or :set timeout timeoutlen=1000 ttimeoutlen=100... Any ideas? (Cygwin, VIM compiled from source)

Comment: You're not using tmux or screen, are you?

Comment: No, Cygwin on Windows 7 64 bit, Mintty terminal emulator, vim compiled from latest source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question...

Mintty has a tip to resolve this:

http://code.google.com/p/mintty/wiki/Tips#Avoiding_escape_timeout_issues_in_vim

Basically add the following to your `.vimrc` file

```
let &t_ti.="\e[?7727h"
let &t_te.="\e[?7727l"
noremap <Esc>O[ <Esc>
noremap! <Esc>O[ <C-c>
```